# Can I configure filebeat decode_xml to start part way down the XML tree?

Tags: xml, filebeat

I have an XML field in my logfile that filebeat is parsing. I want to keep the original full field, but decode the field part way down.

eg:

```
<myfield>
  <fred>
    <barney>
       <wilma>
       ...
       </wilma>
    </barney>
    <betty>
       ...
    </betty>
  </fred>
</myfield>
```

So I want to keep the full `<myfield>` in the logs "as is", but also create a new set of individual fields using decode_xml - but I'm not interested in creating individual fields for fred, barney or betty, I just want from "wilma" down....

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I worked it out! Hopefully this might help someone else in future... Something along the lines of:

```
processors:
  - decode_xml:
    field: message
    target_field: xml
    ignore_missing: true

  - copy_fields:
    fields:
      - from: xml.myfield.fred.wilma
        to: wilma
    fail_on_error: false
    ignore_missing: true

  - drop_fields:
    fields: ["xml"]
```